# Como puedo guardar el resultado de una consulta en una variable en PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Estoy desarrollando un procedimiento en **PL/SQL** para leer un archivo **XML** y dentro de el tengo una consulta donde deseo guardar el resultado que esta consulta en una variable.

La siguiente es la consulta en la cual deseo que su resultado se almacene en una variable:

```
SELECT TEXTO FROM gzvcatg
         UNPIVOT ((codigo, texto) FOR gzvcatg_external_code IN (
        (gzvcatg_external_code1, gzvcatg_desc1) AS '1')
         WHERE GZVCATG_GROUP = 'TIT_ELEC'
            AND CODIGO = 'PATH';
```

El siguiente es el procedimiento que estoy desarrollando para leer el archivo **XML**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_FILEUPLOAD_XML IS

        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO SPRCMNT (
                         SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE,
                         SPRCMNT_TEXT,
                         SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR)
                                VALUES(P_CMTT_CODE,
                                       P_TEXT,
                                       P_TEXT_NAR);    
             EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
             ROLLBACK;           
        END;
    END LOOP;    
END;
```

Necesito saber como puedo almacenar el resultado de la consulta en una variable para luego usarla como parámetro de la función `BFILENAME` en mi procedimiento

**ACTUALIZACION**:

El resultado de mi consulta es la ruta de una carpeta en una sola linea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: está como incompleto, no veo parámetros en el procedimiento ni tampoco es claro la relación entre la consulta, el procedimiento y XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es una seleccion unica (una sola lina) puedes cargarla en tu variable haciendo:

```
SELECT TEXTO INTO my_var FROM gzvcatg
         UNPIVOT ((codigo, texto) FOR gzvcatg_external_code IN (
            (gzvcatg_external_code1, gzvcatg_desc1) AS '1')
         WHERE GZVCATG_GROUP = 'TIT_ELEC'
            AND CODIGO = 'PATH';
```

**EDIT**

En la seccion de declaracion de variables del procedure puedes definir la variable como:

```
myvar gzvcatg.gzvcatg_desc1%TYPE;
```

Comment: Revisa nuevamente mi pregunta realice una actualización, coloque el resultado de mi consulta que si es una sola linea, como hago para declararla en el procedimiento ?

Comment: Puedes hacer lo siguiente en la zona de DECLARE de tu procedimiento:  'myvar    gzvcatg.TEXTO%TYPE'

Comment: Puedes agregarlo en tu respuesta, para darle continuidad a la validez de la misma

Comment: Fijate que ya esta editada

Comment: Es la zona donde tienes declaradas todas tus variables abajo de la definicion del nombre y parametros del procedimiento. Esa es la zona de **DECLARE** de un procedimiento.

Comment: Disculpa, el nombre de la columna en la tabla es gzvcatg_desc1. hice un edit en la respuesta

Comment: No se si entiendo bien la pregunta, estarías devolviendo mas de una linea en la columna "TEXTO"?

Comment: Si es una sola linea, entonces como pase en la respuesta funciona bien.  Si devolves mas de una linea entonces necesitas usar otra cosa que se llama cursor para ir barriendo los resultados. Si devuelve muchas columnas podes agregar mas variables separandolas con **,**

Comment: No importa, cuando me refiero a `gzvcatg_desc1%TYPE` es para obtener la definicion del tipo de la variable. Mientras todos los posibles campos de descripciones tengan el mismo largo esa variable va a ser suficiente, sino debes cambiar la definicion por `varchar(X)` donde X sea el maximo largo del campo